# jQuery Selector to set value to specific text input field of the same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I have three text input fields with the same name and three text fields that get the file name. I am trying to get the three file names

```js
function getFileData(myFile){
  var file = myFile.files[0];
  var filename  =  [file.name];

  $("input:text").val(filename);
}
```

```html
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<input type="file" id="file_name" name="file_name[]" onchange="getFileData(this);" />
<input type="text" id="file_name_helper" name="file_name_helper[]"/>

<input type="file" id="file_name" name="file_name[]" onchange="getFileData(this);" />
<input type="text" id="file_name_helper" name="file_name_helper[]" />

<input type="file" id="file_name" name="file_name[]" onchange="getFileData(this);"/>
<input type="text" id="file_name_helper" name="file_name_helper[]" />
```

The code above sets all the fields to the file name. I want to set only the field that matches the file input field.

Is there a jQuery selector to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your HTML stands, you can use [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) like:

```
$(myFile).next('input[type=text]').val(filename);
```

**Please Note:** The attribute [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) must be unique in a document. If you want to refer multiple elements with same attribute, use [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) instead.

```js
function getFileData(myFile){
  var file = myFile.files[0];
  var filename = [file.name];

  $(myFile).next('input[type=text]').val(filename);
}
```

```html
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> . 
</script>
<input type="file" class="file_name" name="file_name[]" onchange="getFileData(this);" />
<input type="text" class="file_name_helper" name="file_name_helper[]"/>

<input type="file" class="file_name" name="file_name[]" onchange="getFileData(this);" />
<input type="text" class="file_name_helper" name="file_name_helper[]" />

<input type="file" class="file_name" name="file_name[]" onchange="getFileData(this);"/>
<input type="text" class="file_name_helper" name="file_name_helper[]" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
    function getFileData(myFile){
           var file = myFile.files[0];
           var filename  =  [file.name];

           $(myFile).next().val(filename);
         }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> . 
    </script>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    </head>
    <body>
      <input type="file" id="file_name" name="file_name[]" onchange="getFileData(this);" />
      <input type="text" id="file_name_helper" name="file_name_helper[]"/>

      <input type="file" id="file_name" name="file_name[]" onchange="getFileData(this);" />
      <input type="text" id="file_name_helper" name="file_name_helper[]" />

    <input type="file" id="file_name" name="file_name[]" onchange="getFileData(this);"/>
    <input type="text" id="file_name_helper" name="file_name_helper[]" />




    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

On the clicked input find the next input element using next function of jquery and fill the text input

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> . 
</script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
</head>
<body>
  <input type="file" id="file_name" name="file_name[]" onchange="getFileData(this);" />
  <input type="text" id="file_name_helper" name="file_name_helper[]"/>

  <input type="file" id="file_name" name="file_name[]" onchange="getFileData(this);" />
  <input type="text" id="file_name_helper" name="file_name_helper[]" />

<input type="file" id="file_name" name="file_name[]" onchange="getFileData(this);"/>
<input type="text" id="file_name_helper" name="file_name_helper[]" />


<script>
   function getFileData(myFile){
   var file = myFile.files[0];
   var filename  =  [file.name];

   $(myFile).next('input').val(filename);
   }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```